# How come the UIActionsheet like this?

Tags: uiactionsheet

[image]
Anyone knows what's problem this?

[image]
The normal one:

Answer (score 1):

The UiActionSheet like first screen is come, then you count of buttons more than 7. Add some buttons to you second screen and you have UiActionScreen like first.

Answer (score 0):

`UIActionSheet` will allow the buttons to scroll if the number of buttons you've provided won't fit in the area you've presented it.